# Keeping URL parameters after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a questionnaire app, where before the questionnaire begins, the interviewer will first ask to check the interviewee's details, and update them if necessary. To do this, the app switches from the questionnaire controller to the edit form on the member controller. When this is done, it then needs to go back to the questionnaire controller to begin the questions. Because this app works with different questionnaires, the 'questionnaire' and 'memberid' parameter must stay in the url at all times. However, when I submit the form after editing details, these parameters are lost from the url, the start link will not work without them.

I have read that hidden_field_tags should be used, however I am struggling to get them to work...

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "questionnaire", params[:questionnaire] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "memberid", params[:memberid] %>
```

I am also a little unsure what I must put in the controller for this to work. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `link_to` helper, then you should be able to pass parameters like this:

```
link_to "link title", some_path(:questionnaire => "that other one", :memberid => 9)
```

Of course, you've to include extra parameters when you're doing redirects as well.

Also you may consider storing information in a session. Here is some basic overview:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have also tried altering the redirect_to in the update action of the members controller, like so.. **redirect_to(:controller => 'members', :action => 'show', :questionnaire => params[:questionnaire], :memberid => params[:memberid])**... however none of the extra parameters appear in the following url.

Comment: How about: redirect_to member_path(:questionnaire =>2) or redirect_to member_path(:questionnaire => { params[:questionnaire]}) ? Can you catch params in the controller you're redirecting to by adding a throw and check what you're getting there?

Comment: Unfortunately these redirects do nothing either. What do you mean 'adding a throw'? It's looking like I may have to spend some time adding sessions if we I cannot get to the bottom of this!

Comment: add a line: throw params just below the def show, in the controller you're redirecting to. Your app will blow up since you've not caught this throw, but you'll see what you got in params in the backtrace.

Comment: I've managed to get it working! I'm not even sure what I was doing wrong before, probably a spelling mistake or something. I have marked your answer as correct as I used the redirect method you specified, thanks for all your help!